# how can i show data on a page of something i chose in another page

Tags: php

I am making an events website, i am supposed to make an events list and when i click on an event i should get a new page containing its details (get all the data from mysql)

i created the events list loop so everytime event data is inserted it shows up in the list, i made another php page with only the design.

so i want the page to get the data of the event i clicked on from the database and display it so that i don't have to make a new one each time i create an event.

how can i do that??
is it with event_id??

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with 'event_id'. Create a page or route for 'event_details'. You can pass the id as a GET parameter to the 'event_details' page. The 'event_details' page will then use the 'event_id' passed to it to query the database and get the details to display.

A sample url would be 'yoursite.com/event_details.php?event_id=5555'

For the listing page.

event_listing.php

```
<?php

// I'm assuming you fetched the data as associative array
foreach($stmt as $row){
    // This assumes the 'id' column was generated via auto-increment, otherwise, encode it
    $event_id = (int)$row["id"];
    echo "<a href='event_details.php?event_id=" . $event_id . "'>" . $row["event_name"] . "</a><br>"
}
```

event_details.php

```
<?php

// Null coalesce (??) is a php 7 feature.

$event_id = $_GET['event_id'] ?? null

if($event_id){
    $event_id = (int)$event_id;

    //Lookup the database using event_id and use the results.

}else{
    //Display 404 error
}
```

Comment: can you show me how to do that? like what should I put on the event listing page and what to put on the event details page. thanks in advance

Comment: I've edited to add a code sample. I assume you know how to use php with mysql.